# how can I use css and js outside of public folder in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

i am using laravel 4. Here my css and js are not in public folder. I want to access them through another folder. 
I know that by default we can access css and js from public folder only in laravel.
Please help me on this to access from outside of public folder.

Comment: show us your directory structure please.

Comment: -app
-bootstrap
-css
-images
-public
-vendor
I want to use css from CSS folder of this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldnt be made, it has a reason why the structure is like that. The user can only see scripts in the public folder, that has the advantage that he can not execute scripts.

If the css/js/img files come from a Laravel package try `php artisan asset:publish [package]`